# Issues with table display in CSS and further ideas

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have the following code below that focuses on table display.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mother {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: peachpuff;
  display: table;
}

.child {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the child boxes (`.child`) are not totally wrapped, leaving some little whitespaces. The question is, is it because of `display: table` or `display: inline-table`? If yes, what `display` value(s) should I use to prevent leaving whitespaces?

My another concern is, when I change the `display` value of `.mother` to `table` and `.child` to `table-cell`, the children elements fits themselves no matter the width of the parent element. For example, if the `.mother` has a width of 300px and each children is 100px wide, each row is supposed to contain only 3 child elements to perfectly fit the length of the parent element. With `display: flex`, it can be solved with `flex-wrap`. What property should I use in this problem?

Comment: add to your .child this: vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 1):

Add `font-size: 0` to the parent element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mother {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: peachpuff;
  display: table;
  font-size: 0;
}

.child {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a good trick, but what does `font-size` have to do with whitespaces and layout?

Comment: @jst16 They are created from whitespace between tags, `font-size: 0` is one of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/2571493).

Comment: I didn't know `font-size` can be useful not just for texts and fonts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because `display:inline-table` for children. It makes them behave as separate inline-level containers wrapped in the single anonymous 'cell' of the outer table.

Unfortunately, there is no table row wrapping in CSS table display. The only way to move cells to the new row is using extra wrappers with `display:table-row`. And why `display:flex` doesn't fit?

Comment: is `inline-table` for parent or children?

Comment: It's for parent. It behaves the same way as `table` inside (with its own rows and cells), but like `inline-block` outside. It's to `table` as `inline-block` is to `block`.

Comment: so, is `inline-block` okay?

Comment: Both are OK for some cases, but neither will make children behave as the cells of the parent `table`. Both inline blocks and inline tables behave as independent containers that are sized by content by default, and whitespace characters (including tabs and line breaks) between them are rendered as small text fragments consisting of one whitespace character. They both don't use any advantage of the parent's table display except automatic width by content (not used in this example since the width is fixed) and margin collapsing prevention.

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mother {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: peachpuff;
  display: table;
  font-size: 0;
}

.child {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
  margin: -5px -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

It's a bit hacky but it might solve your issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: Remove the background: peachpuff and that shadow goes away.